# Grab Google tasks via Google Calendar API?

Tags: api, task

Does anyone know if you might be able to grab google tasks using the calander API? I took a quick look at the API and I did not see any obvious way to grab the tasks information but it might be doable depending on how the tasks data is used in calander.

I was hoping someone more familiar with the calander API might be able to shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet!
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=987

Comment: Thanks for the link. It actually pointed me to something that I could definatly use for my project:
http://github.com/nickspacek/Net-Google-Tasks/blob/master/main.pl

Answer (score 2):

[Tasks API](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/) has been [announced](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-organized-with-tasks-api.html) at Google I/O 2011.